# Drag and drop operation with Visio ActiveX in C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, drag, visio

I am trying to drag and drop an object from my own application into Visio. Visio does not have the events DropEnter, DropLeave which will make my life easier. Is there any way to communicate both applications with drag and drop operations?